# filterd records in Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data, jpql, hibernate-onetomany

Hi Have two entity employee details and address with one to many relation ship.

**Employee Entity**

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "employeeInfo")
 public class EmployeeInfo { 
   int employeeId;
   String employeeName;

   @OneToMany
   @JoinColumn(name = "employeeId")
   private List<Address> employeeAddress;
 }
```

**Address Entity**

```
@Entity
 @Table(name = "address")
 public class Address{ 
 int employeeId;
 String address;
 String landMark;
 String addressType
}
```

in the above structure, the employee has multiple addresses like

```
Home address, work address, permanent address current address
```

whenever I am trying to get entity by spring data

```
public EmployeeInfo findByEmployeeId(int employeeId)
```

it is returning me the result with four address. is there any way to get the address on the bases of condition

**For example**

```
select * from employeeInfo where address ="homeAddress" and employeeId =1;
```

Comment: is the type of address "homeAddress" or is it a value in the table?

Comment: type is the column name and value is Home address, work address, parmanent address current address

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question completely, please also add Address Entity in the question.

Comment: How do you store multiple addresses in your Database? Please post your Database Schema too

Comment: I update the address entity.

Comment: you can use @Query on top of your method, see the [Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation) -- > 5.3.4. Using Query

Comment: @nitinverma How do you store this Address in your Database? Is it flat or is it a JSON?

Comment: No. The employees' addresses are the employee's addresses, whatever the way yo got that employee. If you want an address of an employee, then query for the address, not for the employee. Or query for the address in addition to querying for the employee: `select employee, address from Employee ...`

Comment: i am storing as a complete address with type of address

Comment: @ JB Nizet I am following jpa association could you please answer how can i get the details

Comment: What is the key to `employeeId` in Address?

Comment: @nitinverma I can't understand what you're asking me. Elaborate.

Comment: @Maruthi Adithya By mistake, Question updated !!  employeeId and address type is the composite  key

Comment: @JBNizet how can i write the query in jpa please explain me

Comment: `select e, a from EmployeeInfo e join e.employeeAddress a where e.id = :id and a.addressType = :type`. Read the documentation. Experiment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically want to retrieve an address of a **known** employee, so you could query for an **address**:

`select a from address a where a.adressType= :type and a.employeeId = :id`

or you could take advantage of the '*Spring Data repository query derivation mechanism*'
and add this method in you `AddressRepository`:

`Address findByAddressTypeAndEmployeeId(String type, Integer id)`

***EDIT***

if you need other fields/data you could use a DTO.

```
 public class EmployeeAddressInfo{
   String employeeName;
   Address address;
   EmployeeAddressInfo(String employeeName, Address address){
       this.employeeName = employeeName;
       this.address = address;
   }
   //getters setters
 }
```

and create this DTO in you `EmployeeRepository`

```
  @Query(select new com.example.EmployeeAddressInfo(employeeName, address)  from employeeInfo  where address.addressType =:type and employeeId =:id)
  EmployeeAddressInfo findAddressInfo(String type, Long id);
```

or you could use other types of [projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections)

Comment: I agreed with your answer but i want address information with employee details in a single query. as I have "@onetomany" mapping between employee and address, so its returning employee details with all the addresses. but my requirement is i need only address based on the type.